# How to perform RealmQuery for two conditions

Tags: java, android, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to get an object from a list but with two specific conditions.

Here's the models

```
Class Car extends RealmObject{
    int id;
    RealmList<Model> models;
    /*
    other .. 
     */
}

Class Model extends RealmObject{
    int id;
     /*
    other .. 
     */
}
```

I get all the cars like this

```
RealmResults<Product> cars = realm.where(Car.class).findAll();
```

When I'm trying to get a specific car that has NO models.. I do this.

```
Car theCar = realm.where(Car.class).equalTo("id", selectedCar.getId()).findFirst();
```

But now.. I want to get a specific car that has a specific model ???

```
// this doesn't work
Car theCar = realm.where(Car.class).equalTo("id", selectedCar.getId())
                  .where(Model.class).equalTo("id", selectedModel.getId())
                  .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the link queries in realm

```
 Car theCar = realm.where(Car.class)
                       .equalTo("id", selectedCar.getId())
                       .equalTo("model.id", selectedModel.getId())                    
                      .findFirst();
```